# Difference between pointer to data type and data member

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C and I have difficulty in understanding difference between two statements which are pointers

```
double **X;
```

and

```
double** X;
```

Are both same?

**Also one more question.**

When do we actually get a situtation to use pointer to a pointer like above `**X`

Comment: Those two variable declarations mean the same thing. The `*` is the dereference operator, so it reads *the value that (the value that `X` points at) points at is a double.*

Comment: This one `double** X;` can be confusing in my opinion and it's ugly. Other than that, why would they be different? And `double * * X` would be the same too or `double**x`. White spaces are not really very relevant for this, they are good to add clarity to the code and I encourage you to use them as much as possible to make the code clear, to distinguish tokens from each other for the human eye, but are otherwise useless.

Comment: @zenith I don't think that's a very good duplicate. I found this one just by googling.

Comment: Thanks aioobe and iharob for the explanation. It is clear now

Comment: do i delete this question since it is duplicate...?

Answer (score 0):

Both of those examples are the same. It defines a type of `X` as a pointer to pointer to double.

An array is a continuous fragment of memory that you access by pointer to it's first element. If you have an array of arrays then type of it is `'whatever element type is'**`.

For example strings are arrays of chars, terminated by '\0' byte. So array of string is of type `char**`

Example usage is really common thing, `main()` function, that can be declared as follows

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

so `argv` is an array of strings that are arguments or your program, `argc` is its' length.

Comment: string are array of chars, terminated by '0' byte???

Comment: yes, I mean byte with value 0. To determine length of string, functions that process it asume that it ends as soon as a NULL byte appears in it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman: more accurately, strings are sequences of characters terminated by a zero-valued byte.  Strings are *stored* as arrays of `char`.

Comment: Yes, zero valued byte, thanks.

Comment: `char **` is not an array. It is a pointer to pointer. Similar (but not identical) semantics make them usable **like** arrays.